# Creating a single output stream out of three other streams produced in parallel

Tags: text-processing, pipe, split, parallelism

I have three kinds of data that are in different formats; for each data type, there is a Python script that transforms it into a single unified format.

This Python script is slow and CPU-bound (to a single core on a multi-core machine), so I want to run three instances of it - one for each data type - and combine their output to pass it into `sort`. Basically, equivalent to this:

```
{ ./handle_1.py; ./handle_2.py; ./handle_3.py } | sort -n
```

But with the three scripts running in parallel.

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/spreading-stdin-to-parallel-processes) where GNU `split`was being used to round-robin some stdout stream between n instances of a script that handles the stream.

From the split man page:

```
-n, --number=CHUNKS
          generate CHUNKS output files.  See below
CHUNKS  may be:
 N       split into N files based on size of input
 K/N     output Kth of N to stdout
 l/N     split into N files without splitting lines
 l/K/N   output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines
 r/N     like 'l'  but  use  round  robin  distributio
```

So the `r/N` command implies "*without splitting lines*".

Based on this, it seems like the following solution should be feasible:

```
split -n r/3 -u --filter="./choose_script" << EOF
> 1
> 2
> 3
> EOF
```

Where `choose_script` does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ read x; ./handle_$x.py; }
```

Unfortunately, I see some intermingling of lines - and lots of newlines that shouldn't be there.

For example, if I replace my Python scripts with some simple bash scripts that do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./handle_1.sh
while true; echo "1-$RANDOM"; done;
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./handle_2.sh
while true; echo "2-$RANDOM"; done;
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./handle_3.sh
while true; echo "3-$RANDOM"; done;
```

I see this output:

```
1-8394

2-11238
2-22757
1-723
2-6669
3-3690
2-892
2-312511-24152
2-9317
3-5981
```

This is annoying - based on the man page extract I pasted above, it should maintain line integrity.

Obviously it works if I remove the `-u` argument, but then it's buffered and I'll run out of memory as it buffers the output of all but one of the scripts.

If anyone has some insight here it'd be greatly appreciated. I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: Some people in #bash on freenode suggested that I spawn all three processes and background them, writing to custom FDs, then loop over those FDs and read lines for them, but I haven't figured out how to make that workable. I was also told to look at the `coproc` builtin in bash, though I don't really see how it applies.

Comment: Do you have to do it without intermediate files? Couldn't you just do `job1.py > file1 & job2.py > file 2 & job3.py > file3 ; wait ; sort -n file1 file2 file3` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the -u option of GNU parallel.

```
echo "1\n2\n3" | parallel -u -IX ./handle_X.sh
```

This runs them in parallel, without buffering the entirety of any process.

Comment: I'm a little confused - is the `X` in `IX` telling `-I` that X will be the flag for replacing, or is it applying the `-X` flag, which seemingly also has a relevant meaning?

Comment: Hmph. I'm doing this: `parallel -u -X ./handle_{}.sh ::: "1" "2" "3"`, and unfortunately I'm still seeing some output mangling.

Comment: the former: you can also use `parallel -u ./handle_{}.sh`, but I prefer to change it, since braces also have the meaning of joining together commands (as in your question).

Comment: Seems to work for me, my grep doesn’t pick up any mangling: http://pastie.org/5113187 (are you using the test bash scripts, or your actual Python scripts?)

Comment: The problem is that that's not actually doing anything in parallel. I'm using the bash scripts - http://pastie.org/5113225

Comment: By default, parallel will run with n_cores processes, I have 4 cores, and htop is showing each ./handle_N.sh process as running 100% on different cores. Having said that, I don’t know what the problem is… I’m running bash 4.2.37 and GNU parallel 20120422.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the problem with your pastie example was that it wasn't doing anything in parallel, as there was no equivalent to argument expansion or explicit argument to spawn N processes, and that was my suspected reason you weren't seeing the mangling.

Comment: If you do not want mangling dont use '-u'. From 'man parallel': should only be used if you do not care about the output

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
parallel ::: ./handle_1.py ./handle_2.py ./handle_3.py
```

If `handle_1.py` takes a file name:

```
parallel ::: ./handle_1.py ./handle_2.py ./handle_3.py ::: files*
```

You do not want the output mixed, so do not use -u.

If you want to keep the order (so all handle_1 output is before handle_2 and thus you might be able to avoid sorting):

```
parallel -k  ::: ./handle_1.py ./handle_2.py ./handle_3.py ::: files*
```

If you still want it sorted, you can parallelize the sort and utilize `sort -m`:

```
parallel --files "./handle_{1}.py {2} | sort -n"  ::: 1 2 3 ::: files* | parallel -j1 -X sort -m
```

Set $TMPDIR to a dir that is big enough to hold the output.

Comment: I do want the output 'mixed' - I just want to make sure that every line in the final output is a single line from one of the subprocesses. If I dont mix it, the system will run out of memory buffering the stdout streams that aren't being printed out yet.

Comment: With GNU Parallel you will not run out of memory: It does not buffer in memory. Why do you think it buffers in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just do:

```
(./handle_1.py & ./handle_2.py & ./handle_3.py) | sort -n
```

If you want lines from each process not to be interleaved, the easier is probably to make sure that the process themselves write them fully and possibly disable output buffering as `write`s to a pipe are guaranteed to be atomic as long as they're not bigger than `PIPE_BUF`. For instance, you could make sure it **does** use output buffering à la `stdio` and call `fflush` or whatever the equivalent is in `python` after one or a few lines have been written.

If you can't modify the python scripts, you could do:

```
lb() { grep --line-buffered '^'; }
```

(with GNU grep) or:

```
lb() while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done
```

(See notes in comments below if what the commands output is not text)

And do:

```
(./handle_1.py | lb & ./handle_2.py | lb & ./handle_3.py | lb) | sort -n
```

Another option to avoid those 3 `lb` processes is to have three pipes to one command that uses `select`/`poll` to see where there's some output coming from and feed it to `sort` line-based, but it takes a bit of programming.

Comment: You need a `wait` in there, I think.

Comment: No unless some of the programs close their stdout before exiting, because the pipe and `sort -n` will remain until all programs that have an fd open on it have exited.

Comment: Indeed, I tested, you are correct.

Comment: No, I still get mangled output. Lines get mixed together and interleaved.

Comment: OK @Cerales, see my updated answer

Comment: Great answer.  You may want to do `IFS= read -r l || [ -n "${l}" ]` in case the last line of output is not terminated with a newline.

Comment: @RichardHansen. That's true, but I'm not sure it's worth complicating the answer to cover for this pathological case. Note that the behaviour for text utilities like grep for such input is unspecified (by POSIX). For instance, GNU grep adds back the missing LF character which may not be what you want (though in this case, it's likely to be what the OP would want). While we're at it, we may also want to cover other kinds of non-text output like overlong lines or lines which contain NUL characters...

Answer (score 1):

Flowbok's answer was the correct solution. Oddly, the output of GNU `parallel` gets mangled if it's output directly to a file - but not if it goes to a tty.

Fortunately, `script -c` is available to mimic a tty.

There are still the three scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
# handle_1.sh
while true; do echo "1-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"; done
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash
# handle_2.sh
while true; do echo "2-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"; done
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash
# handle_3.sh
while true; do echo "3-$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"; done
```

Then there's a file that encapsulates the call to parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
# run_parallel.sh
parallel -u -I N ./handle_N.sh ::: "1" "2" "3"
```

And then I call it like this:

```
script -c ./run_parallel > output
```

The lines in output are mixed line-by-line between the output of the different scripts, but they don't get mangled or interleaved on a given line.

Bizarre behaviour from `parallel` - I may file a bug report.